# Div com height automatico menu dropdown

Tags: javascript, html, css

Ola, minha dúvida é o seguinte. vamos supor esse codigo

```html
<div>
<a>teste</a>
<a>teste</a>
<a>teste</a>
<a>teste</a>
</div>
```

Essa div é exibida ao passar o mouse em um botao, ate aqui tudo bem, porem verifiquei em um site um caso parecido porem acontecia o seguinte...a div tinha muitas opções, quando se clicava no menu dropdown, a div se estende ate o fim da tela, se o espaço nao for suficiente para exibir todo o conteúdo ela gera uma scroll, independente em que posição se encontra o menu dropdown, a div so se estende ate o fim da tela, tipo: se o usuario rolou a pagina e o botao do menu dropdown ficou la no rodape da tela, ao clicar no menu...ele faz a div ir ate esse final da tela..mostrando poucas opções e gerando uma scroll na div, estou tentando fazer um igual, porem se eu coloco pra div ter height auto, quando clico no menu...ela ja mostra todo o conteudo e estendendo a div pra fora da tela e não gera o scroll mesmo com o overflow:auto, pois a div com height auto se ajusta ao conteudo e não a tela, não sei se deu pra entender mas resumindo, quero uma div que se estenda apenas ate o final da tela, que ela se ajuste a tela e nunca exiba conteudo que ultrapasse a parte visivel da tela, nesse caso ela tem que criar um scroll. sei que da pra fazer um esquema com javascript, porem quero saber se tem alguma alternativa mais simples que use talvez só css.

Comment: Você pode apresentar o seu exemplo de forma mais completa? Coloca junto o resto do html relevante para a interação, o js e o css que você está usando para esses elementos.

Comment: Leandro é um menu Dropdown comum, com css e html, porém eu não queria que o conteudo da div saisse da tela, veja aqui...https://www.clashofstats.com/rankings/global/players, lá onde tem global, é um menu dropdown, você vai notar que toda vez que expandir ele, independente da posição ele nunca ultrapassa a tela, eu queria algo semelhante a isso.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Bom eu montei um drop de teste aqui que acho que faz o que você queria, eu no caso coloquei uma altura `max-height` fixa, mas você pode controlar seus elementos e sua hierarquia para deixa-la 100% e fica exatamente o tamanho da tela como você citou, ou fazer isto por javascript.
Mas queria apenas mostrar para você a funcionalidade do `max-height` juntamente ao `overflow:auto`, o overflow faz aparecer a barra de rolagem, ao selecionar auto, ele vai verificar se há conteúdo para fora de seus limites e adicionar a barra de rolagem. E caso não tenha conteúdo para fora de seus limites, ele não adicionará esta barra.

**Apenas HTML e CSS (com vários elementos para ficar maior q a tela)**

```css
* {padding:0; margin:0;}
html, body {width:100%; height:100%;}
ul, li {list-style:none;}
a {cursor:pointer;}
nav {float:left; width:100%; background:#e0e0e0;}
nav > ul > li {display:inline-block; padding:5px;}
nav > ul > li > ul {position:absolute; top:0; background:#666; width:200px; display:none; max-height:100%; overflow-y:auto;}
nav > ul > li:hover > ul {display:block;}
nav > ul > li:hover > ul li a {display:block; width:100%; padding:5px 0;}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>MenuDropDown</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Apenas HTML e CSS (com poucos elementos para ficar menor que a tela)**

```css
* {padding:0; margin:0;}
html, body {width:100%; height:100%;}
ul, li {list-style:none;}
a {cursor:pointer;}
nav {float:left; width:100%; background:#e0e0e0;}
nav > ul > li {display:inline-block; padding:5px;}
nav > ul > li > ul {position:absolute; top:0; background:#666; width:200px; display:none; max-height:100%; overflow-y:auto;}
nav > ul > li:hover > ul {display:block;}
nav > ul > li:hover > ul li a {display:block; width:100%; padding:5px 0;}
```

```html
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>MenuDropDown</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Utilizando Javascript (jQuery)**

```js
$(document).ready(changeMaxHeight);
$(window).resize(changeMaxHeight);
function changeMaxHeight(){
  var $dropdown = $('.dropdown');
  var $maxHeight = $(document).height();
  
  // $dropdown.css('max-height', $maxHeight+'px');
  $dropdown.css('max-height', ($maxHeight - 28) +'px'); // Caso queira retirar a altura do elemento "nav" é só subtrair a altura dele. Caso não queira só descomentar a linha acima e remover esta.
}
```

```css
* {padding:0; margin:0;}
ul, li {list-style:none;}
a {cursor:pointer;}
nav {float:left; width:100%; background:#e0e0e0;}
nav > ul > li {display:inline-block; padding:5px; position:relative;}
nav > ul > li > ul {position:absolute; top:100%; background:#666; width:200px; display:none; overflow-y:auto;}
nav > ul > li:hover > ul {display:block;}
nav > ul > li:hover > ul li a {display:block; width:100%; padding:5px 0;}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<nav>
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a>MenuDropDown</a>
      <ul class="dropdown">
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
        <li><a>Link</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

Espero ter ajudado.

Comment: Obrigado pela ajuda, porem o que eu queria esta nesse site clashofstats.com/rankings/global/players, verifica que la em Global tem um menu dropdown, em qualquer lugar que você expandir ele, ele nunca passa da tela....ele se redimensiona e gera o scroll, queria saber se existe uma forma de fazer isso sem javascript.

Comment: Editei o post com o que você queria, mas como eu disse anteriormente, você terá q controlar seus estilos e suas hierarquias para o `max-height:100%` funcionar, e também controlar muito bem o posicionamento de seu dropdown para não ficar no lugar errado na tela. Eu aconselho fazer por javascript. não é dificil, irei editar jaja o post com a maneira de como fazer via javascript jQuery.

Comment: Aldo, não precisa, não estou uso jQuery, quando ao caso..percebi no codigo fonte do site que eles usam o max-height para limitar a div ao tamanho da tela, agora falta saber se o que eles usam para definir esse valor adaptavel.

Comment: Editei o código com o jQuery javascript, eles devem usar exatamente isto, eu continuo usando o `max-height` mas agora eu pego este valor variável conforme o tamanho da tela, e altero ele caso a tela seja redimensionada.

Comment: Se você for naquele site, abrir o drop, e ver o max-height, alterar a altura de seu navegador para um tamanho menor do que já estava aberto, e reabrir o drop deles, você vai ver que o valor não é o mesmo e é inserido apenas após abrir o drop, isto indica uso de algo além do HTML e CSS

Comment: Aldo, consegui aqui, colocando isso no evento do botao, ele define o max-height ate a area visivel da tela document.getElementById('dropper').style.maxHeight = window.pageYOffset + 'px', obrigado pela ajuda.

Comment: Exato, com o jquery daria para fazer assim também facilmente, era só subtrair também o offset top do elemento dropdown :) Fico feliz por ter ajudado. Caso tenha gostado da resposta, se puder de um up vote. Obrigado.